# APN settings in android

Tags: android, apn

In my Android applications I would like to check if the APN settings set is the preferred APN.

Can I have a list of APN in android?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this list of APN's, it is from CyanogenMod 6.

http://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/blob/573afdd74db101ee6f20f3bd1c9976648414c834/prebuilt/common/etc/apns-conf.xml

Answer (score 1):

Key thing is the content provider URI: "content/telephony/carriers".

Please check this example of APN list handling:

[code example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217131512/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx)

Comment: That example is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The preferrede access point name depends on the network provider. You don't **really** want a list of APN's for all the phone companies in the whole world...?

Answer (score 0):

You have two databases, on keeps list of all the APN's that can be used, and second is preferred APN.
Construct your list from one, and get preferred APN from another.